# Symfony server:run error

Tags: symfony, nginx

I'm getting this error when I'am trying to run `myproject`, symfony2 project. I think that the error came up because on that port `8000` I have `ajenti` server running with `nginx`.

```
Server running on http://127.0.0.1:8000

Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
  RUN  '/usr/bin/php5' '-S' '127.0.0.1:8000' '/srv/myproject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php'
  RES  1 Command did not run successfully
```

What should I do ?

I checked files permissions. `sudo chmod 777 -R /srv/myproject`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the command like this:

```
php app/console server:run 127.0.0.1:8080
```

to run the server on port 8080 or change the port to your own preference

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem! I was unable to access the symfony application from remote machine ... after running this command with my server's IP (instead of `127.0.0.1`), it worked.