# PHP Symfony2 server run terminates unexpectedly

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, composer-php, server

I'm starting to learn PHP Symfony2 Framework. I have a PC with Windows 7 and Wamp manager 2.2 and it includes PHP 5.4.3 and Apache 2.4.2.

I followed these steps to attempt installing and running a Symfony2project:

```
c:\> php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony.phar
c:\> mkdir projects
c:\> move symfony.phar c:\projects
c:\projects\> php symfony.phar
c:\projects\> php symfony.phar new my_project_name
c:\projects\> php app/console server:run
```

The issue I'm having is just in the last step, because it's throwing this error:

```
C:\Users\Jessai\projects\my_project_name>php app/console server:run -v
Server running on http://127.0.0.1:8000

Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
  RUN  "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe" "-S" "127.0.0.1:8000" "C:\Users\Jessai
\projects\my_project_name\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBun
dle\Resources\config\router_dev.php"
  RES  -1073741819 Command did not run successfully
Built-in server terminated unexpectedly
```

And surprisingly there's only [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847403/symfony-serverrun-error) about this and it didn't help me because I changed the port as it says and didn't work, also I reinstalled from **Composer**. I have seen also that there are some warnings like:

```
[...Notice: Undefined index: PATH in phar...]
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it a bug?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the zip file ([in this link](http://symfony.com/download?v=Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.6.4.zip)) and copied directly to the htdocs/www folder. I have to advice everybody that instructions contained in Symfony2 website are confusing. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For me [the doc was helpful](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html#starting-the-web-server).

In particular I used another port then default:

```
php app/console server:run 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Then in browser:

```
http://localhost:9000/
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I would say that youre trying to run the built in php server when you have a wamp server running already.

Comment: I tried to run the command as you said (without starting WAMP) and it's the same error and error code. What else can you suggest me?

Comment: Don't bother with the php server, run was,  type localhost into your browser and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable eAccelerator in your php.ini file.

Comment: mu4ddi3 assumes OP is using Apache server

Comment: i had a similar problem with OP, i solved it by ditching in-built web server and using Apache server.