# server terminated unexpectedly,symfony 3 ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, symfony

I am new to ubuntu.I am using symfony 3 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When i run php bin/console server:run it gets started but as i try to open it in my browser as localhost:8000. It shows [ERROR] Built-in server terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: Include the code in your questions, maybe there's something wrong with it but we can't tell without actually seeing it.

Comment: try php app/console server:run 127.0.0.1:9000 (different port) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842819/php-symfony2-server-run-terminates-unexpectedly . Also you may actually have simply a PHP exception..

Comment: I tried with different port but getting the same issue azhar@azhar-Inspiron-N5010:/var/www/neemka.com$ php bin/console server:run 127.0.0.1:9000
 [OK] Server running on http://127.0.0.1:9000                                                                           
// Quit the server with CONTROL-C.                                                                                     [ERROR] Built-in server terminated unexpectedly.                                                                       
Run the command again with -v option for more details.

Comment: and when i run the command using -v it shows      RUN  '/usr/bin/php5' '-S' '127.0.0.1:8000' '/var/www/neemka.com/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php'

Comment: I gave it a fresh start and now its working well upto welcome page of Symfony but as i enter my first controller url it stops,i think whenever there occurs an error in my code,the server gets terminated.Now its showing        RES  139 Command did not run successfully

 [ERROR] Built-in server terminated unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2):

It was an permissions issue with log files.I changed the permissions and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the debug URL when testing.
So in your case try posting the following URL in your browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php
```

The debug URL might show more useful information.

You can also edit the app_dev.php file to allow other hosts (remote) to access it. It's located in the `web` folder. The line to edit to allow remote hosts contains the following code: `!(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'])`

Just add your remote IP address in there, for example:
`!(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['192.168.0.20', '127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'])`